# Unable to show toast in fragment using this

Tags: android, android-fragments, this, android-toast

I am new in android development. I am trying to show Toast in fragment using following code which i got from other sites:

```
Toast.makeText(this, "count is " + count, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

But I am getting an issue in the first parameter. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [getActivity()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getActivity%28%29), which returns the activity associated with a fragment.
The activity is a context (since Activity extends Context).

So your code will be like this:

```
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "count is " + count, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

use `getActivity()`

```
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "count is " + count, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you see the signature of the method `makeText` of the `Toast` class you can see that the first parameter required is the Context.

A fragment is not a subclass of Context so using the `this` keyword you are passing the Fragment object.

You have to use `getActivity()` or `getContext()` method.

```
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "count is " + count, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

If you want to know the difference read this post [What is the difference between this getcontext and getactivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30278290/what-is-the-difference-between-this-getcontext-and-getactivity)

Answer (score 0):

1) You can use **getActivity()** instead of using **this** keyword. The code will be like below,

```
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Count is" + count, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Override fragments **onAttach(Context)** method and store **context** for all calls which requires context.

```
class MyFragment extends Fragment{
   private Context _context;
   @Override
   protected void onAttach(Context context){
     _context = context;
   }

  private void showToast(){
     Toast.makeText(_context, "count is " + count, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`
  }    
}
```